# How to pass an Array and the current index to a method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, parameter-passing

I want to sort an array using the **swap()** method as shown in the code. I want to know how to pass the array and sort it.

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] ar = {9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 8, 4, 2, 0};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
        for (int i = 0; i<ar.length-1; i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j<ar.length; j++){
                swap(ar[i], ar[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
    }
    private static void swap(int i, int j) {
        int temp;
        if(i>j){
            temp = j;
            j = i;
            i= temp;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You declare a method parameter of array type: `int[] ar`.

Comment: You mean I have to declare it like:private static void swap(int [], int []){...}

Comment: No, you add a *third* parameter for the array

Comment: You don't have to make a special treatment to a variable if you want to pass it by reference. This is not like C/C++, you just passe the variable as it is. Read : [Is java pass by value or by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: I don't know if this is intended or not but I believe your loop isn't looping through the whole array. Should be `i<ar.length;` unless it's intended of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are just like any other type. If you want to pass an array to a method, declare a parameter of that type, e.g.

```
private static void swap(int[] ar, int i, int j) { ... }
                         ^ This is a parameter of type int[].
```

Note that the `i` and `j` you pass should be indexes, not values in the array:

```
swap(ar, i, j);
```

and swap the elements thus:

```
temp = ar[i];
ar[i] = ar[j];
ar[j] = temp;
```

Comment: Thanks. It was useful.

Comment: @Eid you can also swap the 2 values without a temporary variable: `ar[i]^=ar[j]; ar[j]^=ar[i]; ar[i]^=ar[j];`. Which is a great story to tell when you're with your friends in a pub. But I wouldn't recommend it though.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
private static void swap(int[] ar, int i, int j) {
    //Do work here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot arrays were in place for a second.